# Lambert W Function $\ln(\frac{x}{x_0})=t(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, lambert-w

Suppose that I have to solve $x$ for$$\ln\Big(\frac{x}{x_0}\Big)=t(x+1)$$

This is my attempt,
$$\frac{x}{x_0}=e^{t(x+1)}$$
$$=e^{tx+t}$$
$$x=x_0\cdot e^{tx+t}$$
$$\frac{x}{e^{tx}}=x_0e^t$$
$$xe^{-tx}=x_0e^t$$
$$-txe^{-tx}=-tx_0e^t$$
$$x=-\frac{W(-tx_0e^t)}{t}$$

Am I correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is very correct.

Comment: Are there different "levels" of correctness?

Comment: Thank you. @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: @user247327Because I'm new to Lambert W, I am worried that I applied it wrongly. Thank you.

Comment: After the last step it is worth to note 
that there are none, one or two real solutions, 
depending on the argument of $\operatorname{W}$.